# When is it non-Markovian?

Tags: markov-decision-process

Several months ago, I was writing for class.  I claimed an environment was non-Markovian because it would take several states to de-alias some positions in the grid world.  I was corrected that it was n-step Markovian.  Something that didn't occur to me until the class had ended was:

If there's an n, then n could be infinity.  This would imply an MDP where the next state is decidable with infinite history.  This seems like a reasonable thing to call non-Markovian as it's not decidable within a finite time but is it?  Where does non-Markovian start?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your observation about the possibility of n being infinite makes sense. If an environment requires an infinite unbounded history of states to make decisions, it is considered non-Markovian. However, in the strict mathematical sense of (1st order Peano) arithmetic supposed to model all the natural numbers, any specific number n in its domain is finite, no matter how big it is. Thus your n-step Markovian is not non-Markovian as considered above.